# WPF MVVM compliant way to open views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would love to find a simple and MVVM compliant way,
to open a new view from the MainWindow.

I have already worked through some instructions and tutorials.
But somehow none really worked or it was a mixture of code behind.

I would like to open a view after pressing a button and edit an ObservableCollection in it.

I have already created DataTemplates in App.xaml and mapped the ViewModels with the respective views.
But I don't know how to cleanly open a separate window from the MainWindow (MainViewModel) via an ICommand for another ViewModel.

Comment: I use services. It's a separate dll that exposes Interfaces, you call that from ViewModel or View. It doesn't break MvvM this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should't open a window directly from the `MainWindow` nor the `MainWindowViewModel`. But the view model may use a service to open a window:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly IWindowService _service;
    public MainWindowViewModel (IWindowService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    //...
    public void OpenWindowExecuted()
    {
        _service.ShowWindow();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public interface IWindowService
{
    void ShowWindow();
}

public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public void ShowWindow();
    {
        Window window = new Window()
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

You could easily mock out the service in your unit tests.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code! How can I trigger the service via the ViewModel?

Comment: @br0ken.pipe: I've already showed you an example of how to this in my answer. See the `OpenWindowExecuted()` method. This method could be executed from a command that the view invokes.